# Ruby on mac not installing gem showing permission denied

Tags: ruby, macos

I am trying to install a ruby gem in My Machine using xcode where I call a shell script.

cd  "/Users/Desktop/gemfolder"

gem install somegem.gem

I am getting an error like this:

```
While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
```

Any workaround for it I am a newbie to ruby so don't know what to do anyhelp will highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use the system-provided Ruby.  You can install Ruby using Homebrew.

Comment: how to install that and use that instead of 1.8

Comment: Take a look at rbenv for installing Ruby.  It's also installed via Homebrew.  rbenv: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv  homebrew: http://brew.sh/

Comment: or another [ruby version manager](https://rvm.io/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being `sudo` might fix your problem, however when you are installing gems , its not a good idea to install them as `sudo`, so the preferred way of installing ruby on any machine is to install [rvm (Ruby Version Manager)](https://rvm.io/) first and then install your ruby version.

Main advantages of having a ruby version manager are,

1 - allows you to install multiple ruby versions side by side

2 - allows you to install gems for each ruby version (via gemsets)

So to install rvm in your mac, [check here](http://rvm.io/rvm/install)

[list of ruby version managers](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/ruby_version_management)

Comment: You can install w/out sudo by setting the `--user-install` flag, e.g. `gem install --user-install somegem.gem`.  This will install into a folder in your home directory like `~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/` and does not require `sudo` privileges.